# Cannot install zone on Solaris 11

Tags: solaris, solaris-zones

I am trying to install a *zone* on Solaris 11. I am using [these instructions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-admin/o11-092-s11-zones-intro-524494.html).

I get up to *Listing 2* when the error occurs.

```
    # zoneadm -z testzone install
    The following ZFS file system(s) have been created:
        rpool/zones/testzone
    Progress being logged to /var/log/zones/zoneadm.20140522T025544Z.testzone.install
           Image: Preparing at /zones/testzone/root.

   ERROR: an exception occurred.

        'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind'

       Please check logs for further information.
   ERROR: auto-install failed.
```

The install log is:

```
root@solaris-11:~# cat /var/log/zones/zoneadm.20140523T065105Z.testzone.install
    [Fri May 23 16:51:05 EST 2014] ==== Starting: /usr/lib/brand/solaris/pkgcreatezone -z testzone -R /zones/testzone ====
    [Fri May 23 16:51:05 EST 2014] Progress being logged to /var/log/zones/zoneadm.20140523T065105Z.testzone.install
    [Fri May 23 16:51:08 EST 2014]        Image: Preparing at /zones/testzone/root.
    [Fri May 23 16:51:12 EST 2014] Running auto-install: '/usr/bin/auto-install -z testzone -Z rpool/zones/testzone/rpool -m /tmp/manifest.xml.PCa4ad -c /usr/share/auto_install/sc_profiles/enable_sci.xml'
    [Fri May 23 16:51:14 EST 2014] ERROR: auto-install failed.
    [Fri May 23 16:51:14 EST 2014] Exiting with exit code 255
    [Fri May 23 16:51:14 EST 2014] ==== Completed: /usr/lib/brand/solaris/pkgcreatezone -z testzone -R /zones/testzone  ====
```

Zonecfg results:

```
    root@solaris-11:~# zonecfg -z testzone export
    create -b
    set brand=solaris
    set zonepath=/zones/testzone
    set autoboot=true
    set bootargs=-m verbose
    set ip-type=exclusive
    add anet
    set linkname=net0
    set lower-link=auto
    set configure-allowed-address=true
    set link-protection=mac-nospoof
    set mac-address=random
    end
```

Zonecfg info:

```
    root@solaris-11:~# zonecfg -z testzone info
    zonename: testzone
    zonepath: /zones/testzone
    brand: solaris
    autoboot: true
    bootargs: -m verbose
    file-mac-profile:
    pool:
    limitpriv:
    scheduling-class:
    ip-type: exclusive
    hostid:
    fs-allowed:
    anet:
        linkname: net0
        lower-link: auto
        allowed-address not specified
        configure-allowed-address: true
        defrouter not specified
        allowed-dhcp-cids not specified
        link-protection: mac-nospoof
        mac-address: random
        mac-prefix not specified
        mac-slot not specified
        vlan-id not specified
        priority not specified
        rxrings not specified
        txrings not specified
        mtu not specified
        maxbw not specified
        rxfanout not specified
        vsi-typeid not specified
        vsi-vers not specified
        vsi-mgrid not specified
        etsbw-lcl not specified
        cos not specified
        pkey not specified
        linkmode not specified
    root@solaris-11:~#
```

Comment: Looks like there's a problem in your zone config. Run `zonecfg -z testzone export` and post the contents here.

Comment: pkg publisher ?

Comment: I'm not sure who the publisher is. What do I run to find out?

Comment: @Kinesia What is the output from `pkg publisher`

Comment: Can your test system's global zone resolve and reach pkg.oracle.com ?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is that the global is not pointing to a valid publisher for solaris.

You want to see something like this on the global:
`Solaris11-global [14]# pkg publisher
PUBLISHER       TYPE     STATUS P LOCATION
solaris         origin   online F https://pkg.oracle.com/solaris/support/`

And verify that the svc:/application/pkg/zones-proxyd:default
 service is online on the global as well.

Good luck.